# Как реализовать на JavaScript простой однотонный звук (Beep)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, аудио, ecmascript-6

На C++ мы можем воспроизвести простой однотонный звук используя [Beep](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/utilapiset/nf-utilapiset-beep) из WinAPI. JavaScript уже давно [реализует](https://caniuse.com/#search=AudioContext) функциональность по динамичному созданию звука как полноценными, так и мобильными браузерами ([AudioContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/AudioContext)). Однако, простого примера именно с однотонным сигналом я не нашел. Подскажите реализацию человеку без музыкального образования...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Покапавшись в теории, написал реализацию однотонного звука. Оказалось, не так уж и сложно: правда, нужно ждать клика от пользователя для разблокировки API в Chrome, не очень удобно при написании игр...

```js
let context = null;

    const beep = (freq = 520, duration = 200, vol = 100) => {
        const oscillator = context.createOscillator();
        const gain = context.createGain();
        oscillator.connect(gain);
        oscillator.frequency.value = freq;
        oscillator.type = "square";
        gain.connect(context.destination);
        gain.gain.value = vol * 0.01;
        oscillator.start(context.currentTime);
        oscillator.stop(context.currentTime + duration * 0.001);
    }
    
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
        context = new AudioContext();
        beep();
    });
```

```html
 <button>Click</button>
```

Эта технология позволяет [генерировать саундтрек налету](https://gist.github.com/tripolskypetr/a793967504aa6fcc0d3ebb30d1642dec), уменьшив размер дистрибутива до минимального (10 цифр вместо отдельного файла с музыкой)

Comment: Там напрашивается оптимизация кода.

Answer (score 1):

Этот пример воспроизводит последовательность нот, как на рисунке и учитывает длительность каждой ноты:

```js
var notes = [
 [-7, 0, 3, 7, -1, 0], // высота
 [0.125, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.125, 1] // длительность
];
context = new AudioContext();
oscillator = context.createOscillator();
oscillator.type = "square";
oscillator.connect(context.destination);
document.body.onclick = function(){
 index = 0;
 nextnote();
 oscillator.start(context.currentTime);
}
function nextnote(){
 oscillator.frequency.value = 440 * Math.pow(1.06, notes[0][index]);
 var mytimeout = notes[1][index] * 2000;
 index ++;
 if(index >= notes[0].length){
  oscillator.stop();
 }else{
  setTimeout(nextnote, mytimeout);
 }
}
```

Для запуска кликните в любом месте страницы.

Comment: Не, эт была просто красивая картинка)

Comment: Что-то у меня ничего не воспроизводится.

Comment: Что пишет консоль?

Comment: Если не поддерживается web-audio api, есть ещё вариант в обход.